# Rake task is slower with Activerecord queries in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

After I upgraded to rails 3.1.0 version my custom rake task which uses some ActiveRecord queries is slower now. I couldnt find the real cause of this. My rake version is 0.9.2 . Is there any work around for this? Some one please help me on this.